# Numbered list with Cyrillic letters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, localization

In Google Docs, I would like to have a numbered list using Cyrillic letters, such as:

```
а  
б  
в  
г  
д
```

The regular choices for numbered lists offer the options of Arabic numerals, Latin lowercase, Latin uppercase, Latin lowercase numerals, or Latin uppercase numerals.  I can make it a bulleted list and select an arbitrary symbol for each bullet point, thus manually selection абвгд, etc., but this is cumbersome and error-prone.  How can I automatically have a numbered list that is enumerated using (lowercase) Cyrillic letters?

There's a [similar question about Hebrew letters on the Google Support forum](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0tP1k-ZFkzIk/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/docs/tP1k-ZFkzIk), but it is from 2014 and unanswered; [wisdom of the ancients it is](https://xkcd.com/979/)...

Comment: Why the [tag:google-apps-script] tag was included? If you are looking to do this with Google Apps Script please add a brief description of your attempts to write the script by yourself or to adapt something that you found.

Comment: @Rubén I did not add this tag, user0 did so in [their edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/132244/2), I don't know why.  I don't know anything about google apps scripts and I am preferably looking for a solution that already exists.

Comment: Have you already tried to change the document language to one that use the Cyrillic alphabet and to change your account language to one of them?

Comment: @Rubén I think the document language is already Russian (spell-check is Russian).  I did not try to change my Google Account language to Russian and I really don't want to do that (I could try to see if it would work, but as a solution it would not be satisfactory to me).

Comment: Have you already take a look to [russian.se]? I don't know if using word processors from american companies in Russian is on topic there, but maybe you could find other guys facing the same problem there and with a lot of luck having one of them to come here and share their findings.