# Format Chinese number as numbered list in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I would like to use [Chinese numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals) as numbered list in Google Docs, similar to unanswered question [Numbered list with Cyrillic letters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/132244/10492), But I can't find any useful options in `Format > Bullets & numbering`.

[image]

In Chinese, The character `一` is number 1 in Arabic, `二` for number 2, and so on.

```
一、List item 1
二、List item 2
三、List item 3
```

Instead of

```
1. list item 1
2. list item 2
3. list item 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I've configured each list item manually in list options/more bullets by changing symbol to Han 1, then manually select "1." on the list then replace it with "一“ from the Han 1 options, then change to Han 2, and repeat the process